# Necesito ayuda con formularios

Tags: php, formularios

Quiero hacer un programa que te muestre una suma con números aleatorios, te pida una solución y al ponerla te diga si has acertado o has fallado, a parte tiene que contar los fallos y los aciertos y contar el tiempo que te cueste hacer un número de veces esa suma. Hasta el momento he hecho en un documento la suma, en otro he hecho un formulario y este con POST se envía a otro que te dice si has acertado o has fallado, pero no sé cómo hacer que vuelva a mostrar la suma ni que cuente los fallos y aciertos, este es el código de la suma:

```
$num = array(rand(1000,9999),rand(1000,9999),rand(1000,9999));



foreach ($num as $numeros) {

    echo $numeros. "</br>";

}



$resultado = array_sum($num);



?>
```

Este el código del formulario:

```
<html>
<head>
 
<style>
 
.error {color: #FF0000;}
 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
 
$res = "";
 
$reserr = "";
 
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 
  if (empty($_POST["res"])) {
 
    $reserr = "Este campo es requerido.";
 
  } else {
 
    $res = test_input($_POST["res"]);
 
    if (!filter_var($res, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
 
      $reserr = "Sólo números";
 
    }
 
    }
}
 
function test_input($data) {
 
  $data = trim($data);
 
  $data = stripslashes($data);
 
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
 
  return $data;
 
}
 
include 'suma.php';
 
$t = $resultado;
 
?>
 
<form action="prueba.php" method="post">
 
  <input type="hidden" name="prueba" value="<?php echo $t; ?>"/>
 
  <input type="text" name="res">
 
  <span class="error"><?php echo $reserr;?>
 
  </span>
 
  <br><br>
 
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Si pongo "" No me hace la comprobación ni me muestra error si lo introducido no es un número, pero si pongo "<form method="post" action="">" Me hace la comprobación pero al enviar se recarga la página cambiando el resultado y nunca acierto.

Y el código de prueba:

```
<?php
 
$val = $_POST['res'];
$val2 = $_POST['prueba'];
echo $val;
echo "</br>";
echo $val2;
echo "</br>";
if ($val != 0) {
    if ($val == $val2) {
        echo "Has acertado";
    } else {
        echo "Has fallado";
    }
}
 
?>
```

Mi nivel de php no es muy alto y no veo una solución a todo, necesito ayuda

Comment: ¿Por qué usas PHP para esto? Sería más simple usar JavaScript.

Comment: Porque me han dicho que tenía que ser con PHP

Comment: Si es un ejercicio debes decir las pautas, que puedes usar y que no puedes usar. Por ejemplo, ¿puedes usar Ajax, o no? Si no puedes entonces tendrás que usar variables de sesión para ir guardando la información.

Comment: Creo que sí que tengo que utilizar variables de sesión, pero no se exactamente como se utilizan, sé lo que son pero nunca las he utilizado

Comment: Hola @RutBorillo, te damos la bienvenida al sitio. Por favor completa el [tour] y lee sobre [ask] y [answer] donde encontrarás recomendaciones para que tus publicaciones sean mejor recibidas.

Answer (score 0):

Como bien te comentó @A.Cedano, PHP no es la opción más adecuada para este ejercicio, aunque se puede lograr usando variables de sesión; el principal problema sería con el manejo de tiempos, porque hay que considerar que hay "tiempos muertos" entre que PHP genera el código y el navegador lo interpreta; lo mismo al procesar el formulario.

Todo el código está con comentarios para que sepas cómo funciona cada cosa, lo único por aclarar es la forma en que se generan los números:

- `new Array(3)` crea un arreglo con espacio para 3 elementos, inicialmente está vacío
- `.fill()` llena todos los espacios con *undefined*, es una preparación para poder asignar valores
- `.map()` recorre los elementos y asigna valores al azar
- `Math.random()` genera números de punto flotante entre cero y 1, por eso es que se usa `parseInt()`, para convertirlo a entero, se multiplica por la diferencia entre número máximo menos mínimo y se suma el mínimo. [Más información y ejemplos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/random).

```js
let nums, segundos, inter,
  aciertos = 0,
  errores = 0;


// Todos los input en un array de 4 elementos, 3 de valores y uno de suma
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
// Botón comenzar y comprobar
let comenzar = document.querySelector('#comenzar');
let comprobar = document.querySelector('#comprobar');
// Elementos que se deben actualizar: tiempo y resultado
let tiempo = document.querySelector('#tiempo');
let resultado = document.querySelector('#resultado');

function jugar() {
    // Llenar arreglo de números al azar
    nums = new Array(3).fill().map((_, i) => parseInt(Math.random() * (9999 - 1000) + 1000));
    // Llenar inputs con valores del arreglo
    nums.map((a, i) => inputs[i].value = a);
    // Activar input para suma
    inputs[3].disabled = false;
    inputs[3].focus();
    // Desactivar botón comenzar y activar comprobar
    comenzar.disabled = true;
    comprobar.disabled = false;
    // Limpiar div de resultados
    resultado.innerText = '';
    // Inicializar tiempo y mostrar
    segundos = 0;
    tiempo.innerText = segundos;
    // Actualizar tiempo cada segundo
    inter = setInterval(function() {
        segundos ++;
        tiempo.innerText = segundos;
    }, 1000);
}
function comprueba() {
    // Dejar de contar tiempo
    clearInterval(inter);
    // Desactivar input de suma y botón comprobar, activar botón comenzar
    inputs[3].disabled = true;
    comenzar.disabled = false;
    comprobar.disabled = true;
    // Obtener valor del campo suma o cero si está vacío
    total = parseInt(inputs[3].value) || 0;
    // Sumar los valores del arreglo y comparar con entrada del usuario
    correcto = nums.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    if(total == correcto) {
        resultado.innerText = 'Acertaste';
        aciertos ++;
    } else {
        resultado.innerText = 'Error, el resultado correcto es: ' + correcto;
        errores ++;
    }
    resultado.innerHTML += `<br>
        <b>Total de aciertos: ${aciertos}</b><br>
        <b>Total de errores: ${errores}</b><br>
        Click en "Comenzar" para probar nuevamente.`;
}

// Asignar evento a botones
comenzar.addEventListener('click', jugar);
comprobar.addEventListener('click', comprueba);
```

```css
input {
  width:120px;
  font-size:2em;
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<p><button id="comenzar">Comenzar</button></p>

<input type="number" id="num1" disabled><br>
<input type="number" id="num2" disabled><br>
<input type="number" id="num3" disabled><br>
<input type="number" id="suma" placeholder="Suma &nbsp;" disabled>
<div>Tiempo: <span id="tiempo"></span></div>
<button id="comprobar" disabled>Comprobar suma</button>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

**Nota:** Si tengo oportunidad, más tarde o mañana agrego una opción con PHP.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Me han dicho que tiene que ser con PHP y no veo una salida clara, los tiempos ni idea y el contador no se hacerlo sin un bucle, pero tampoco sé dónde iniciarlo ni qué condición... Voy perdida.

Answer (score -2):

Al final lo he hecho con ajax, sí que se podía, para no recargar el formulario y las respuestas las he acumulado con sesiones, lo único que no he conseguido es calcular el tiempo de la forma que quiero

Comment: Por favor sé más específic@, la respuesta a esta pregunta le puede servir a futuros usuarios.

Comment: Hola Rut, debes dar más detalles sobre la respuesta. Ten en cuenta que otros usuarios puede tener un problema similar y una respuesta detallada les será de ayuda. Considera añadir más información como ¿por qué y cómo usaste AJAX? (¡en los comentarios de la pregunta decías que no se podía!) ¿qué código usaste? ¿dónde iría el código? Lee [answer] para más información.